# Automatically executing actions according to the current location

Tags: software-recommendation, system-settings, geolocation

I would like to have in my MacBook Pro a functionality which execute automatically some actions according to my current location. This actions could be for example

- Change the default printer
- Change the network location (for setting for example static or dynamic IP like in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68464/is-there-a-free-program-for-easily-managing-network-locations/68473#68473))
- Open an application or a specific file
- Activate/Deactive file sharing
- Run shell scripts

The current location could be inferred for example by using the current network (Wi-Fi network name) or other localization services.

Is there an application that provides this functionality?

Comment: Have you looked into the Locations feature in the Network prefpane?

Comment: @Gerry Yes I did. That's what is reported in the question I linked. However I'm looking for an automatic way to switch from one location to another. And I also want to change the default printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [Control Plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/about/):

> **ControlPlane** allows you to build configuration profiles, contexts in ControlPlane lingo, for your Mac based on where you are or what you are doing.  ControlPlane determines where you are or what you are doing based on a number of available evidence sources and then automatically reconfigures your Mac based on your preferences.  Evidence sources can include your current location, visible WiFi networks, attached USB devices, running applications and more.  You can even write your own evidence sources using shell scripts!